# kusto: Calcuating duration

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a kusto table where I will receive data every 2 hours. I need to find the start and end time for a given data. Here, endtime should be determined by the system by seeing if the data is not present for that message.

Eg:

```
Id Name Timestamp
1   A   07-12-2022T04:05:00z
2   A   07-12-2022T06:05:00z
3   A   07-12-2022T08:05:00z
4   A   07-12-2022T12:05:00z
```

In the above example, we received data at 4,6,8 and it is missing for 10. I need to show that the start time is 04"05"00 and end time as 10:00:00 (here the system should detect and fill-in) and then one more start time as 12:05:00z without and end time as the current time is less than 2 hours from 12:05:00.

Comment: What do you think you'll gain from putting a fictive end time? The last record you've seen was from 08:05:00 what's the point of making it 10:00:00?

Comment: I want to show that the issue is resolved at 10 and then it started again at 12

Comment: **(1)** Posted a solution. If you wish you can add 2h EndTime. I think it's a mistake **(2)** When working with dates use only the UTC format (yyyy-MM-dd etc.) **(3)** The data sample that you created does not reflect your actual scenario. I'm guessing that you want to apply your logic per `Name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let p_max_allowed_gap = 2h;
datatable(Id:int, Name:string, Timestamp:datetime)
[
    1 ,"A" ,"2022-07-12T04:05:00z"
   ,2 ,"A" ,"2022-07-12T06:05:00z"
   ,3 ,"A" ,"2022-07-12T08:05:00z"
   ,4 ,"A" ,"2022-07-12T12:05:00z"
]
|   partition   hint.strategy=native by Name
    (
            order by    Timestamp asc 
        |   extend      session_id = row_cumsum(iff(Timestamp - prev(Timestamp) > p_max_allowed_gap, 1, 0))
    )
|   summarize   StartTime = min(Timestamp), EndTime = max(Timestamp) by Name, session_id 
|   extend      EndTime = iff(now() - EndTime < p_max_allowed_gap, datetime(null), EndTime)
```

| Name | session_id | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 2022-07-12T04:05:00Z | 2022-07-12T08:05:00Z |
| A | 1 | 2022-07-12T12:05:00Z | 2022-07-12T12:05:00Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22Sy26DMBBF90j8w4gVlpzKuOlDtKnURRfddNPsqgo5sZNYwgbZzlP9%20A6hBKIylsA2x3fuBUoVoC6MOBSiLKu9ksVa1DADvnmKIykCjkWp0neZaxsofAijch%20ctmsKc22UD8LUOYIq4IrE0VccAVYGNHlN8MIZ5xP2MMn4nE1zdpczdkrODOVjzP01czvGPF4z0xEm4z3zHUc/yNXCBR10ZXG%20wTQ3mAN9r48zK4LeKVgcz/naAGl766pyUrmGwLrkBuGX0HNNE3UIysp27ZX32K7QEl%20oq/bFcmv81qR6tUp7jQnUTu36DQIv/78IhYwCI6RtRtpAqGWE0yeF88%20A6RoNbGW0HchReLOyeyIOw0Z/genQaSs9jNEfb4zbap8SNN3tPo%20Z7f6H1G7LsndAfgFz330VbgIAAA==)